# List's ForEach() method not acting as expected

Tags: c#, foreach

Why is this not working?

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    test.Add(i);

test.ForEach(t =>  t = ++t);
```

The elements in test are not incremented.

Comment: Just wrap your values into a class.

Comment: If you need a 1 to 20 range, it's easier to use `Enumerable.Range(1, 20)`

Comment: @FelixK. It's way easier to just use a `for` loop than to go through that.  Also note that class semantics may not be desirable elsewhere in his code.

Comment: Another reason why you should avoid `List<T>.ForEach`...the notion that you can have side effects confuses people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) isn't part of LINQ. It's been in .NET since 2.0.

> Elements in test are not incremented

No, they wouldn't be. The parameter to `Action<T>` is passed by *value*, not by *reference*. Changes made to the parameter (`t` in your case) aren't visible to the calling code - and even if they were, there's no guarantee that `List<T>.ForEach` would use them.

Note that if you had a reference type (e.g. `StringBuilder`) as the list element type, and made changes to the data in the object that the parameter value referred to, e.g.

```
builders.ForEach(x => x.Append("Foo"))
```

then those changes *would* be visible in the list, because they're not changes to the list at all - the list would contain the same references as before, just to *objects* whose data happened to have changed.

Answer (score 5):

Ints are values, not references.

Plus a foreach doesn't allow manipulation of the collection elements.

So it's a double fail i'm afraid :(

What would work:

```
for(int i=0;i<test.Count;i++)
    test[i]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `t` variable that you have is a *copy* of the item in the list.  You are modifying a copy, and as such the item in the list itself isn't affected.  To increment each item in the list you can use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < test.Count;i++
    test[i]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected result.

You wouldn't expect the following to actually increment `x` in `Main`, so your lambda example is no different.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    Increment(x);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}");
}

static void Increment(int x)
{
    x = ++x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
test.Add(i);
for(var z = 0 ; z < test.Count; z++)
{
    test[z]++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers , i knew the alternatives but i was intrigued why this was not working, i stumbled upon it at work today, after using linq with sql for such a long time i didn't realize i was using primitives like int.Thanks